# Flask-CORS not working for POST, but working for GET

Tags: python, flask, cors, axios, flask-cors

I'm running a Flask-Restful API locally and sending a POST request containing JSON from a different port. I'm getting the error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

However, when I run

```
curl --include -X OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/comments/3
        --header Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
        --header Access-Control-Request-Headers:Content-Type
        --header Origin:http://localhost:8080
```

I get

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: HEAD, GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Length: 0
```

which shows "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" as "*". GET works fine, it's just POST that gives this error. What could be going wrong? If relevant, for the frontend I'm using react and requesting through axios.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I have landed in the same exact situation, any updates would help.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, a CORS error raised because of an internal error. An error completely unrelated to CORS, which should return 500, was causing this.

Comment: How did you finally discover that it was 500 error?

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})` into your flask app.

Hope that solves the issue.

Comment: for more info about CORS see: https://stackabuse.com/single-page-apps-with-vue-js-and-flask-ajax-integration/

Comment: thanks, unfortunately also with the added resources it still only works for me for get

Answer (score 5):

the Flask-Cors docs explain why this might happen

> "When using JSON cross origin, browsers will issue a pre-flight OPTIONS request for POST requests. In order for browsers to allow POST requests with a JSON content type, you must allow the Content-Type header. The simplest way to do this is to simply set the CORS_HEADERS configuration value on your application: e.g."

https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/

```
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
```

Comment: What should you put instead of "content-type" in order to allow browser to run an angular app that is requesting data from the server?

Answer (score 1):

In Post request browser send an OPTIONS request as a pre-flight request before it excutes post so enabling the **OPTIONS** request on your server with proper CORS headers will resolve this issue.

The CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error occurs when a web application running in a browser tries to make a request to a different domain (origin) than the one it was loaded from. CORS is a security mechanism implemented in web browsers to prevent cross-origin requests by default, for security reasons.
The basic logic behind the CORS error is as follows:

1. When a web application running in a browser makes a request to a different
   domain, the browser automatically sends an HTTP request called a
   "preflight" request to check if the cross-origin request is allowed.
   The pre-flight request is of **OPTIONS** type.
2. The server receiving the preflight request must respond with appropriate
   CORS headers indicating that the cross-origin request is allowed.
3. If the server does not respond with the necessary CORS headers or responds
   with incorrect headers, the browser blocks the actual request and throws a
   CORS error.

The CORS headers that the server should include in its response are:

1. **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: Specifies the allowed origin(s) for the cross-
   origin request. It can be a specific domain or '*' to allow requests from
   any origin.
2. **Access-Control-Allow-Methods**: Specifies the allowed HTTP methods for the
   cross-origin request, such as GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
3. **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**: Specifies the allowed headers for the cross-
   origin request, such as Content-Type, Authorization, etc.
4. **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**: Optional header that indicates whether
   the browser should include credentials (e.g., cookies, HTTP authentication)
   in the cross-origin request.

I was using the azure function httpTrigger to run the http post request in my flask application. So allowing options request in **function.json** file resolves the issue for me.

"methods": ["get","post","options"]