# Axios POST resulting in NULL

Tags: api, vue.js, post, flask, axios

This is my flask code,

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
@cross_origin()
def helloWorld():
    data = request.json
    return jsonify(data)
```

I am using axios in Vue to post data to localhost:5000. I am able to post it but in flask it shows null.

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

When I do this in Vue,

```
axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I get the correct output i.e. data posted but in flask I get null as response.
Anyone has idea why this is happening?

Comment: Add CORS to flask: [Flask work with GET, not POST need CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45373545/4911686)

Comment: I've already added CORS in Flask. @Fazel Farnia Is there anything else that's causing this problem

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem currently trying to post to a flask component from a react frontend...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `/` from post address.