# React axios GET null data from Flask backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I have a react form in frontend where users can submit a question they wanna ask. Send the form data to flask server, using some NLP models to compute and get a result. Then return the result to the frontend.

The problem is: I can see the data posted to flask server, but getting null when I try to GET results from flask server.

Here is the handleSubmit method in QuestionForm.js in frontend:

```js
// post data to flask
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/newquestion', this.state)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

componentDidMount() method in QuestionResult.js:

```js
class QuestionResult extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            questionResult: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/newquestion')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({questionResult: response.data})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {questionResult} = this.state

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{questionResult}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The flask endpoint (It is just a test model and I am trying to return the question itself right now):

```js
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/api/newquestion", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_user_question():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_question = request.get_json()
        print(user_question)
    return jsonify(user_question)

app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

This is what I get from python console:

```js
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2019 23:01:12] "OPTIONS /api/newquestion HTTP/1.1" 200 -
None
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2019 23:01:12] "GET /api/newquestion HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'question': 'aaaa'}
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2019 23:01:13] "POST /api/newquestion HTTP/1.1" 200
```

However, when I import another function test.py:

```js
def hello():
    return "hi there!"
```

And changed the endpoint to:

```js
@app.route("/api/newquestion", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_user_question():
    return hello()
```

I can see the message "hi there!" successfully rendered on my react page.

Comment: Check the logs on your API.

Comment: You may need additional configuration with CORS: see both the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/39550920/1453578 if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
const config = {
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
        };

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/newquestion', this.state, config)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({questionResult: response.data,            isLoaded: true})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

```html
@app.route("/api/newquestion", methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*',headers=['Content-Type'])
def get_user_question():
    data = request.get_json()
    question = data['question']
    result = generate_text(question)
    return jsonify(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting server response because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy. In short, browsers do not, by default, let ajax requests to be made to any address which has different port, protocol or domain than your page, unless the server allows it, by adding a certain response header.

In your case means your react app can't communicate with flask server running on a different port, but you can make some changes to flask configuration for allowing cross-origin requests. There are some packages available for this, e.g. https://enable-cors.org/server_flask.html

Comment: I did enable CORS on flask and I have updated my code above.

Comment: What do you get in console after that? you can also view your browser's developer tools to inspect network requests being made by page to your server.

Comment: {data: null, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://localhost:5000/api/newquestion", method: "post", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: null
headers: {content-type: "application/json"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object

Comment: this happens on `componentDidMount`? your API just returns the input right now, and I do not see any additional input in POST request:

Comment: I think the frontend is trying to get the results before posting the data, that's why I'm getting null, but I still don't know how to fix it.