# Flask: issue remains even after enabling CORS

Tags: python, flask, flask-cors

I have test website [here](http://cocostraws.com/).  I have already enabled CORS in my code.

```
app = Flask (__name__,
            static_url_path='',
            static_folder='./')
cors = CORS(app,
            resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}},
            cors_allowed_origins="*",
            async_mode='threading'
            )
socketio = SocketIO(app)
socketio.run(app,port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

This is a sample response:

```
@app.route('/getobsspecieslist', methods = ['GET'])
#@cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
def resp_obsspecieslist():
    response = {}
    # Check if user sent a name at all
    query = """
    select t2.COMMONNAME
    from bird_observation_location_date_v3 t1
        left join ebird_info_dataset t2 on t2.bird_id = t1.bird_id
    group by t2.COMMONNAME
    order by t2.COMMONNAME asc
    """
    resp = []
    res = query_db(query)
    for row in res:
        resp += [{'name': row[0]}]
    response["result"] = resp
    response = jsonify(response)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    # Return the response in json format
    return response
```

Still, it is not working as intended.  I have looked around and tried multiple suggestions to no avail.  Please help!

===============================================================

Further examination shows this error comes first:

```
Error  TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.    index.js:588:17

SetupSpeciesDropdown http://cocostraws.com/script/index.js:588
(Async: promise callback)
SetupSpeciesDropdown http://cocostraws.com/script/index.js:587
_onload http://cocostraws.com/script/index.js:18
onload http://cocostraws.com/script/index.js:2
(Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
<anonymous> http://cocostraws.com/script/index.js:2
```

It comes from this chunk of code:

```
function SetupSpeciesDropdown() {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getobsspecieslist"
    //var url = "http://www.cocostraws.com/getobsspecieslist"
    fetch(url, {mode: 'cors'}).then(res => res.json()).then(function(speciesList) {
        d3.select("select#dropdown")
            .selectAll('myOptions')
            .data(speciesList["result"])
            .enter()
            .append('option')
            .text(function (d) { return d["name"]; }) // text showed in the menu
            .attr("value", function (d) { return d["name"]; }); // corresponding value returned by the button

        d3.select("select#dropdown").on("change", function(d) {
                    // recover the option that has been chosen
                    selectedBird = d3.select(this).property("value");
                    // run the updateChart function with this selected option
                    LoadHeatMapData(selectedBird);
        });
        // Load the map corresponding to the first species in the list.
        selectedBird = speciesList["result"][0]["name"];
        LoadObsHeatMapData(speciesList["result"][0]["name"]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error ', error);   /* this is line 588 */
    });
};
```

Line 588 is from the error handling.  It fails at the earlier fetch.  Could someone point out my error?

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your resource map is incorrect: `r"/*"` matches a string of zero or more forward slashes, you want `r"/.*"` instead. `flask_cors` expects [regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) (using packgage `re`), not glob syntax.

But you may have other problems. `cors_allowed_origins` and `async_mode` are not documented keyword arguments, and you don't need the line `response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')`, this should be handled by the extension.

Finally, do you need to be able to pass credentials? If so, look at the documentation of the `supports_credentials` option... and note that you cannot use it with the origin `*`, it's just too unsafe.

Comment: The two keywords are mistakenly used from `SocketIO`.  I have removed them.  The `resource` map is from @porthunt's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550920/flask-cors-not-working-for-post-but-working-for-get).  I have changed it according to your suggestion.  The header addition has also been removed.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, "not working as intended" is not much to go on. What is the intended and observed behavior? Does the socket communication work at all? What headers does the response send? Do you use authentication? I would suggest you make a proof-of-concept code (just the above code plus what it needs to make it runnable), and edit your question to add the code, response headers and a more detailed description.

Comment: The AJAX requests fail stating `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/.... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`  This is from the console using Firefox when visiting that site.

Comment: Use the firefox console, or `curl`, to display the full response headers. And see above.

Comment: I have updated the question with newer info.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  It is from these two lines:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getobsspecieslist"
//var url = "http://www.cocostraws.com/getobsspecieslist"
```

The problem is that my site does not have `www.` in front.  Changing it to this solves the problem.

```
var url = "http://cocostraws.com/getobsspecieslist"
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know for what you are using CORS header, but if you are doing this for an AJAX request in front-end javascript, using a CORS header will definitely work...See the [W3schools documentation for AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: Hi Arjun, thanks for chiming in.  I am not quite following.  What change in code are you suggesting?